# Import an SQL file to Azure

Tags: sql, azure

I am new to the field and I need some guidance. I want to import an SQL file containing data (~8gb if that matters) in Azure. I have created an SQL database and I want to import it there. Can someone give me some guidance?

Comment: If its a script file, can't you connect to the Azure SQL Database from SSMS (locally) and simply run the script instead of copying the file into a storage?

Comment: @FleminAdambukulam there is data to the file that I want to store

Comment: If you just want to store the file somewhere on Azure, Create a Storage Account on Azure and a file / blob storage inside it and copy the file using Storage Account Explorer (a desktop application that can be used for this purpose)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest BCP to connect to your Azure SQL DB and upload the data directly.

The other way of doing it would be to upload your CSV data to a storage account and [create an external table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935021.aspx) on top of it. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-azure-blob-storage-with-polybase).

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-overview-load#load-from-sql-server) lists some additional ways to do it.